# How to run KVM on non-X environment with Windows 2008 as a guest

Tags: windows, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I has a debian wheezy OS. And it's a non-X environment, but we just wanna install a windowns 2008 on it.But we couldn't install a X environment on my debian.
Could any one tell me howto?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring vnc on the virtual machine and installing a vnc viewer in your desktop.

Here there is a example using the command virt-install of libvirtd

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_a_KVM_Guest_OS_from_the_Command-line_(virt-install)